# Logstash logback encoder failing with java.util.ServiceConfigurationError (jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule could not be instantiated)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logstash, logback

I am trying to have JSON-based logging in my springbootapp (2.4.8). I have followed instructions as mentioned in [github](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder) and some other docs and StackOverflow-related questions. However, I am unable to resolve the issue.

Below is the exeption am getting:

ERROR in net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder@4fcee388 - Error occurred while dynamically loading jackson modules **java.util.ServiceConfigurationError**: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.**JavaTimeModule could not be instantiated**

I did make sure **logstash-logback-encoder** dependency was added and logback dependencies are >= 1.2.0 (am using 1.2.3). Please see excerpt from dependency tree for details.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ <my-spring-boot-app> --
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:6.6:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.3:compile
```

And please see corresponding src/main/resources/logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>
    <logger name="jsonLogger" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Following is the runtime exception am getting:

```
   ERROR in net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder@4fcee388 - Error occurred while dynamically loading jackson modules java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule could not be instantiated
```

Below is the corresponding pom.xml file definitions for dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <scribejava.version>5.6.0</scribejava.version>
    <ch.qos.logback.version>1.2.3</ch.qos.logback.version>
</properties>



<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    <version>6.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. It turned out to be a dependencies issue.

(Basically, with logstash 6.6, jackson.core 2.9.3 threw above error. When i moved to 2.12.1 things started working. Below is actual details of the versions am using - excerpt from dependency tree)

```
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:6.6:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.1:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

for me the error was different , but root cause was dependency issue.
logstash needs jackson version to be in sync.
follow here :https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder/releases
I faced this while upgrading springboot version which inturn upgraded jackson version and caused application startup failure.
for logstash 7.2, jackson upgrade to 2.13.3 worked fine

```html
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder@1a72a540 - Error occurred while dynamically loading jackson modules java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:344)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
```